# Ebook with Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework

Working with latest version of Ionic (3.x). I am working simply on programming an **Ebook** with almost 200 pages (in 4 languages).

I find not good to embed the whole html textes in a one `<ion-content>`. So I thought about a solution more sophisticated, such as dividing into chapters, so I am between 2 solutions (none of them works btw).

**1.** Use `ng-include` which after hours I found out that it is not more supported in Ionic (I hope I'm wrong).

**2.** Create a component for each chapter (the template is the chapter text wrapped in HTML). But I think that this one is **performance-costly** because at program launch there will be creation of many views of the components.
Any better advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I would try to load the entire book's content into the app. I would fetch content on an as-needed basis. You also need a solution that will scale with size of the device display, so the one-component-per-chapter idea is probably not the best choice.

(Additionally, I would take a step back and ask why the book isn't being distributed on already established platforms, e.g. mobi, ePub, etc. But this is outside of the scope of your posted question, of course.)